# Magento 2.2.2 Javascript Bundle error

Tags: javascript, magento2.2

I am currently using **Magento 2.2.2** and all is fine with JS bundling and minifying off.

However, when I enable js bundling I get a JavaScript error. I think this is related to a **require.js** config file. This error only appears when bundling.

When inspecting the compiled js file I notice there is an empty **js build** component. Where is this built from and what steps should I go about resolving this?

If I remove the empty **js build** manually from the compiled js file, there are no problems.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162793)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by a utf8_encode error on a copyright-character in `requirejs-config.js` in the `Mageplaza/Core` module.

When Magento creates the bundle files it uses `json_encode($contents, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)` to create the json string for the bundle. When this fails, it returns an empty string without showing any errors.